# How to print lists (of different length containing colored characters) as columns in Python without using imports?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to print out the following triangle using columns instead of rows:

```
def r(x):
    return '\x1b[6;31;50m{}\x1b[0m'.format(x)


def g(x):
    return '\x1b[1;32;50m{}\x1b[0m'.format(x)


def rb(x):
    return '\x1b[5;31;51m{}\x1b[0m'.format(x)


print(f'1    10    {rb(208)}    {r(1234)}')
print(5*' ', f'{g("1")}     {g("1")}{r("0")}     {g(208)}')
print(12*' ', f'1      {r("1")}0')
print(20*' ', f'{r(1)} ')
```

If I want to add a column as the code is now, I have to add spaces and one element to the end of each print statement. That's not a big deal for this example, but I'm not looking forward to column 50 or 100. I thought I'd just write each column as a separate list instead and then combine them into a list of lists and loop through it, but I got stuck.

Printing one list as a column while keeping the alignment was pretty straight forward, but I don't know how to handle the lists being of different lengths (the spacing is fine, but the fact that all lists will have different lengths got me).

```
col = ['32Σ21', '1234', '208', '10', '1']
col5color = ["33"+r("Σ2")+g("1"), g("12")+r("34"), r("2")+g("08"), rb("10"), r("1")]
maxlen = len(col[0])
for i in range(len(col)):
    print((maxlen - len(col[i]))*' ' + col5color[i])
```

The lists for the first four columns:

```
col4color = [r("1234"), g("208"), r("1") + "0", r("1")]
col3color = [rb("208"), g("1") + r("0"), "1"]
col2color = ["10", g("1")]
col1color = ["1"]
```

To clarify: I can't change the layout (flip rows/columns), I can't use imports and I have to hardcode it. That's why I would like to tidy it up and minimize the risk of errors. If  I could just deal with the different lengths I would only have to add one element at the first index of "col", copy and paste "col", change the name to "colncolor" and then change the colors. I don't know much about the next column beforehand, but I know that the new element will have at least as many characters as the element in the previous column, so I never have to change "maxlen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It's not the best solution or a generic one, but at least it's a solution =)

```
def trimatrix_print(color_matrix, matrix, spacing=4):
    num_col = len(matrix)
    maxlen = len(matrix[0][0]) + spacing
    newmat = []
    for i in range(num_col):
        for j in range(num_col):
            if len(matrix[i]) < num_col:
                color_matrix[i].append(" ")
                matrix[i].append(" ")
            if len(matrix[i][j]) < maxlen and i != num_col - 1:
                color_matrix[i][j] = (maxlen - len(matrix[i][j]))*" " + color_matrix[i][j]
    for i in range(num_col):
        tempmat = []
        for j in range(1, num_col + 1):
            tempmat.append(color_matrix[-j][i])
        newmat.append(tempmat)
    for line in newmat:
        print(''.join(line))
    return


num = [
    ['32Σ21', '1234', '208', '10', '1'],
    ['1234', '208', '10', '1'],
    ['208', '10', '1'],
    ['10', '1'],
    ['1']]

colornum = [
    ["33"+r("Σ2")+g("1"), g("12")+r("34"), r("2")+g("08"), rb("10"), r("1")],
    [r("1234"), g("208"), r("1") + "0", r("1")],
    [rb("208"), g("1")+r("0"), "1"],
    ["10", g("1")],
    ["1"]]

trimatrix_print(colormat, mat)
```